# OpenSSL in C++ email client - server closes connection with TLSv1 Alert message

Tags: c++, client, openssl, ssl

My app connects to a IMAP email server. One client configured his server to reject SSLv2 certificates, and now my app fails to connect to the server. All other email clients connect to this server successfully. My app uses openssl.

I debugged by creating minimal openssl client and attempt to connect to the server. Below is the code with connects to the mail server (using Windows sockets, but same problem is with unix sockets).

Server sends its initial IMAP greeting message, but after client sends 1st command, server closes connection. In Wireshark, I see that after sending command to server, it returns TLSv1 error message 21 (Encrypted Alert) and connection is gone.

I'm looking for proper setup of OpenSSL for this connection to succeed.
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define CHK_NULL(x) if((x)==NULL) exit(1)
#define CHK_ERR(err,s) if((err)==-1) { perror(s); exit(1); }
#define CHK_SSL(err) if((err)==-1) { ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); exit(2); }

SSL *ssl;
char buf[4096];

void write(const char *s){
   int err = SSL_write(ssl, s, strlen(s));
   printf("> %s\n", s);
   CHK_SSL(err);
}

void read(){
   int n = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
   CHK_SSL(n);
   if(n==0){
      int e = SSL_get_error(ssl, 0);
      printf("Read error %i\n", e);
      exit(1);
   }
   buf[n] = 0;
   printf("%s\n", buf);
}

void main(){
   int err=0;

   SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
   SSL_METHOD *meth = SSLv23_client_method();
   SSL_load_error_strings();
   SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);
   CHK_NULL(ctx);

   WSADATA data;
   WSAStartup(0x202, &data);

   int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
   CHK_ERR(sd, "socket");

   struct sockaddr_in sa;
   memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
   sa.sin_family      = AF_INET;
   sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("195.137.27.14");
   sa.sin_port = htons(993);

   err = connect(sd,(struct sockaddr*) &sa, sizeof(sa));
   CHK_ERR(err, "connect");

   /* ----------------------------------------------- */
   /* Now we have TCP connection. Start SSL negotiation. */

   ssl = SSL_new(ctx);                         CHK_NULL(ssl);    
   SSL_set_fd(ssl, sd);
   err = SSL_connect(ssl); CHK_SSL(err);

   // Following two steps are optional and not required for data exchange to be successful.
   /*
   printf("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));

   X509 *server_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);       CHK_NULL(server_cert);
   printf("Server certificate:\n");

   char *str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(server_cert),0,0);
   CHK_NULL(str);
   printf(" subject: %s\n", str);
   OPENSSL_free(str);

   str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name (server_cert),0,0);
   CHK_NULL(str);
   printf(" issuer: %s\n", str);
   OPENSSL_free(str);

   // We could do all sorts of certificate verification stuff here before deallocating the certificate.
   X509_free(server_cert);
   */

   printf("\n\n");

   read(); // get initial IMAP greeting
   write("1 CAPABILITY\r\n"); // send 1st command
   read(); // get reply to cmd; server closes connection here
   write("2 LOGIN a b\r\n");
   read();

   SSL_shutdown(ssl);

   closesocket(sd);
   SSL_free(ssl);
   SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

Comment: You seem to be doing everything by the book (except naming your functions `read` and `write` and confusing me for a second...). Can you provide more information on the error you're getting and the configuration of the server you're connecting to?

Comment: There's the server's IP in the code, you can test the problem on that IP. The error is after SSL_read, SSL_get_error returns 6 = SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the host you are trying to connect to has a buggy TLS implementation. Using the `openssl` command-line tool, I have discovered the following.

First of all, the file `imap` contains a silly IMAP session:

```
A1 CAPABILITY
A2 LOGIN foo bar
```

Then, the command:

```
openssl s_client -ign_eof -crlf -pause -connect 195.137.27.14:993 < imap
```

Fails as follows:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/serialNumber=iGXzgDJpD6t8m5jQNY0xwwcCiwwlXzET/C=GB/O=mail1.firedupgroup.co.uk/OU=GT57369617/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)11/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=mail1.firedupgroup.co.uk
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/serialNumber=iGXzgDJpD6t8m5jQNY0xwwcCiwwlXzET/C=GB/O=mail1.firedupgroup.co.uk/OU=GT57369617/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)11/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=mail1.firedupgroup.co.uk
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3300 bytes and written 439 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID: 9F1200004D888506211A976BF1CC755C873789D8256936638BF9C9E66DAA9438
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: A67DE8C76371B8034AA60447ECB97ED631E55E4E713F64FAA49D2DBAC07A6339719F4C4DD4E1FD2BC5E41EDCC2CF22FE
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1332595025
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
* OK firedupgroup.co.uk IMAP4rev1 MDaemon 9.6.2 ready
closed
```

But the command:

```
openssl s_client -bugs -ign_eof -crlf -pause -connect 195.137.27.14:993 < imap
```

Succeeds:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/serialNumber=iGXzgDJpD6t8m5jQNY0xwwcCiwwlXzET/C=GB/O=mail1.firedupgroup.co.uk/OU=GT57369617/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)11/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=mail1.firedupgroup.co.uk
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/serialNumber=iGXzgDJpD6t8m5jQNY0xwwcCiwwlXzET/C=GB/O=mail1.firedupgroup.co.uk/OU=GT57369617/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)11/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=mail1.firedupgroup.co.uk
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3300 bytes and written 423 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID: 261200008CB526A49A014E97D510AA7FDA08DDAC797B8B78B3ABEEF4A64B3228
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 457E9FFB43C77E028211A0FDB9915FCB374A55445ED15498E2C5AFDBEA52C9A413CC8D79EE29ECA823E038A93363B9D6
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1332595088
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
* OK firedupgroup.co.uk IMAP4rev1 MDaemon 9.6.2 ready
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 NAMESPACE AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN IDLE ACL UNSELECT UIDPLUS
A1 OK CAPABILITY completed
A2 NO LOGIN failed
```

Which means you need to enable OpenSSL's bug workarounds, as described in the [`SSL_CTX_set_options(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html) manual page.

Comment: cha0site: Very good observation, thanks! The problem was solved by SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS);